# priority_queue with custom cmp

Tags: c++, queue

I trying to implement event queue that is sorted by an event field.
So i write something like that:

```
struct MyAlgo 
{
   MyAlgo() {
      // some random generation of positions
      for (auto pos : RandomPostions)
        Queue.push({SiteEvent, pos, NULL});
   }
   struct Event
   {
      EventType Type;
      FVector2D Pos;
      Node* Arc;
   }
   bool cmp(const Event& a, const Event& b) { return a.Pos.Y > a.Pos.Y; }
   std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, decltype(&cmp)> Queue;
}
```

At the and I have no ordered elements on my queue. What's going wrong?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  I should be able to paste the code into one of the online compilers and duplicate the problem. Not like this - live - https://godbolt.org/z/hbxqG3qKa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a static function (to match the signature for the comparison operation). Also, you need to qualify the name:

```
static bool cmp(const Event& a, const Event& b) {
    return a.Pos.Y > b.Pos.Y;
}
std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, decltype(&MyAlgo::cmp)>
    Queue { &MyAlgo::cmp };
```

Also, note that the comparison itself was flawed (it compared the variable to itself, leading to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of inconsistent weak-total-ordering.

### Simplify

Make the comparator a function object instead:

```
struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(const Event& a, const Event& b) const {
        return a.Pos.Y > b.Pos.Y;
    }
};
std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, Cmp> Queue;
```

Now you can't forget to pass the cmp instance to the constructor.

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25283473f7288d4b)**

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

enum class EventType { SiteEvent };
struct FVector2D {
    float X, Y;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, FVector2D const& fv)
    {
        return os << "{" << fv.X << "," << fv.Y << "}";
    }
};

struct Node {
};

struct MyAlgo {
    MyAlgo()
    {
        // some random generation of positions
        for (auto pos : {FVector2D{1, 22}, {2, 3}, {8, 33}}) {
            Queue.push({EventType::SiteEvent, pos, nullptr});
        }
    }

    struct Event {
        EventType Type;
        FVector2D Pos;
        Node*     Arc = nullptr;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Event const& ev) {
            return os << ev.Pos;
        }
    };

    struct Cmp {
        bool operator()(const Event& a, const Event& b) const {
            return a.Pos.Y > b.Pos.Y;
        }
    };
    std::priority_queue<Event, std::vector<Event>, Cmp> Queue;
};

int main()
{
    MyAlgo algo;

    while (not algo.Queue.empty()) {
        std::cout << algo.Queue.top() << "\n";
        algo.Queue.pop();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
{2,3}
{1,22}
{8,33}
```